# How to enable a PowerShell script to return help text when using Get-Help or -?

Tags: powershell

How do I get my PowerShell script to display help when a user requests help via:

```
Get-Help -Name myscript.ps1
```

or

```
myscript.ps1 -?
```

For example, to describe my scripts parameters etc.

**Updated question**

I tried the suggested answers. But I don't see the expected output.

I simply place added the following code to myScript.ps1.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    A short description of your script.

.DESCRIPTION
    A longer description of your script.

.PARAMETER <-silent>
    First parameter is -silent. It will do Collection Bootstrap silently.  

.PARAMETER <action>
   Second parameter is action. Action could be either bootstrap or join

#>
```

When I tired

> Get-Help .\myScript.ps1

, it shows as follows

```
NAME
    C:\es\dev\myScript.ps1

SYNOPSIS
    A short description of your script.


SYNTAX
    C:\es\dev\myScript.ps1 [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    A longer description of your script.


RELATED LINKS

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help C:\es\dev\myScript.ps1 -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help C:\es\dev\myScript.ps1 -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help C:\es\dev\myScript.ps1 -full".
```

I was expecting to see the description of the parameters. I tried both.PARAMETER <-silent> and .PARAMETER -silent.  Same results. What is wrong?

**Related question update 2 after processing more**

I can see the help file after adding parameter section as follows:-

```
param (

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='taskJsonFile', Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$taskJsonFile="tasks.json"
)
```

But very important to see full help file I must use
**Get-help .\myscript.ps1 -full**
Otherwise, it doesn't show full help information.

But here comes my next question. When I tried -full. It shows some irrelevant information. I would like to omit this information to be shown to the user. Now it displays as following:-

> NAME
>       C:\es\dev\myscript.ps1
>
> SYNOPSIS
>       It performs Collection Bootstrapping silently or parameterized based.
>
> SYNTAX
>       C:\es\dev\myscript.ps1 [[-action] ] [[-file] ] [[-sasHostname] ] []
>
> DESCRIPTION
>       For silent operation, user has to fill configuration file with desired value at Eurostep.SAS.Collection Bootstrap.Config.psd1. This
>   configuration file has to exist in
>       the same directory of Eurostep.SAS.CollectionBootstrap.ps1 PowerShell script.
>
> PARAMETERS
>       -action
>
> ```
>     Required?                    false
>     Position?                    2
>     Default value                bootstrap
>     Accept pipeline input?       false
>     Accept wildcard characters?  false
>
> -file <String>
>
>     Required?                    false
>     Position?                    3
>     Default value                bootstrap_collection.json
>     Accept pipeline input?       false
>     Accept wildcard characters?  false
>
> -sasHostname <String>
>
>     Required?                    false
>     Position?                    4
>     Default value                http://localhost:5000
>     Accept pipeline input?       false
>     Accept wildcard characters?  false
>
> <CommonParameters>
>     This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
>     ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
>     OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see
>     about_CommonParameters (https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).
> ```
>
> INPUTS
>
> OUTPUTS
>
> ```
> -------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------
>
> C:\PS>.\myscript.ps1
>
> For silent Collection Bootstrapping no parameter. It reads values from configuration file myscript.Config.psd1
>
>
>
>
> -------------------------- EXAMPLE 2 --------------------------
>
> C:\PS>.\myscript.ps1 bootstrap bootstrap_collection.json 'http://localhost:5000'
>
> All required parameter provided. Note that hostname must be inside ' '. Because it is a link.
> ```
>
> RELATED LINKS

I don't want to show **RELATED LINKS INPUTS OUTPUTS** , etc.

Is there anyway to remove them from help informtion. Even -Full is used?

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to add comment based help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878343(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You just need to put `.PARAMETER silent` and `.PARAMETER action`, its the unnecessary `<`, `-`, `>` characters that is stopping it from working

Comment: I removed `<`, `-` , `>` characters. Still, it is same. No description of the parameters.

Comment: Does your script have a `param()` block?

Comment: No. I don't  have it. Do  I need it

Comment: Yes you need to put variables that you want to be parameters inside a param() block, separated with commas. Otherwise you can’t use them from outside the script as parameters and they aren’t displayed in help.

Comment: Thanks it worked after add param() block. But I need little more help. Please check the update 2. Thanks!

Comment: There are 4 different ways to display help with `get-help`. There's the default output which includes name, syntax, aliases and remarks. You can add the `-Detailed` switch to get name, syntax, parameters (without descriptions), aliases and remarks. You can use `-Full` to get all help fields. You can use `-Examples` to return just the examples. You can also use `-Parameters` to return one or more named parameters (or use * to return them all). I suggest you read the official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to add comment-based help to your script. This is a special comment block that is formatted with specific keywords and then the associated text for those keywords. For example:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    A short description of your script.

.DESCRIPTION
    A longer description of your script.

.PARAMETER SomeParameter
    A description of the SomeParameter parameter.  

.PARAMETER OtherParameter
    A description of the OtherParameter parameter. Have as many of these lines as you have parameters.

.EXAMPLE
    YourScript.ps1 -SomeParameter 'thing' -OtherParameter 1

    Does something. Have as many examples as you think useful.
#>
```

These are the keywords I tend to use by default but look at the full list described here for others you might want to include: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: To clairfy, just copy and paste this to the top of your script.  You can also do this for each Function in a module.  Simply paste the comment block immediately before the `Function` declaration, or inside the `Function`.

Comment: To see full help information one must provide -full parameter.